# Saving data in to a different host in spark scala application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to persist a data frame created out of a kafka topic data in to a different host.
The code i've used:

```
 val topicMaps = Map("topic" -> 2)
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","maprfs://host-2:7222")
val fs =FileSystem.get(conf)

val messages  = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaConf, topicMaps, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)

messages.foreachRDD(rdd=>
{
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val dataframe =sqlContext.read.json(rdd.map(_._2))
val myDF =dataframe.toDF()
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode


myDF.write.format("parquet").mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append).save("maprfs://host-2:7222/hdfs/path")

})
```

The above code has created a path in the host directory, but the data is not being written whatsoever.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you missing `ssc.start()` or is it just not shown here?

Comment: i purposefully removed from this code snippet